# Groovy script to read the xml file and write the node name

Tags: jenkins, groovy

I am working on Jenkins and using Groovy script to automate the deployment process.

To deal with the passwords, i have kept a XML file - **passwords.xml**

```
<APP1>
    <development>
        <schema>
            <db1>pass1234</db1>
        </schema>
    </development>
    <test>
        <schema>
            <db1>pass1234</db1>
        </schema>
    </test>
    <production>
        <schema>
            <db1>pass1234</db1>
        </schema>
    </production>
</APP1>
```

Now I am trying to create a property file like,

```
APP1.development.schema.db1=pass1234
APP1.test.schema.db1=pass1234
APP1.production.schema.db1=pass1234
```

I have written the below groovy script to do so,

```
def passwords_rails_app =  var_workspace + "/passwords.properties"
def passwords = new XmlParser().parseText(props_credential.passwords_url.text)

PrintWriter writer_passwords_rails_app = new PrintWriter(passwords_rails_app)

passwords.'**'.findAll{
  writer_passwords_rails_app.println(it.name() + "=" + it.name())
}
writer_passwords_rails_app.close()
```

But this is simply creating the property file, and not writing the node names in the property file.

Suggest me.

Comment: Please clarify whether you use this code in a Pipeline job script or in a (System) Groovy build step.

Comment: @izzekil - I ran this script inside System Groovy build step.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
  rootNode.APP.each{ APP ->
    APP.development.schema.children().each{ tag ->
        writer_passwords_rails_app.println("${APP.@title}.development.schema.${tag.name()}=${tag.text()}")
  }
    APP.test.schema.children().each{ tag ->
        writer_passwords_rails_app.println("${APP.@title}.test.schema.${tag.name()}=${tag.text()}")
  }

    APP.production.schema.children().each{ tag ->
        writer_passwords_rails_app.println("${APP.@title}.production.schema.${tag.name()}=${tag.text()}")
  }

}
```

Solves the question